# Cannot get a cookie from when I am storing a session into redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis, session-cookies, express-session

I am trying to do Ben Awad's fullstack tutorial. around the 1:56:00 I was trying to login on the backend with graphql, but I am not receiving a cookie for my session, so I cannot stay logged in.

This is the code below, and I am sure I am connected to redis. If anyone know how to possibly get the cookie on my browser that would be perfect. Thank you!

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { HelloResolver } from "./resolvers/hello";
import { PostResolver } from "./resolvers/post";
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/user";
import { MyContext } from "./types";
import redis from "redis";
import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";

const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
  await orm.getMigrator().up();

  const app = express();

  let RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
  let redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 6379,
  });
  redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Could not establish a connection with redis. " + err);
  });

  app.use(
    session({
      name: "qid",
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
        // disableTouch: true,
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 3, //3years
        httpOnly: false,
        sameSite: "lax", // protecting csrf
        secure: __prod__, //cookie only works in https
      },
      saveUninitialized: false,
      secret: "askdjajshdfgkjha",
      resave: false,
    })
  );

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolver, UserResolver],
      validate: false,
    }),
    context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em, req, res }),
  });

  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("server started on localhost:4000");
  });
};

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Is your API returning the cookie and it is not getting set in the browser? Or the API itself is not returning the cookie?

Comment: I am not sure to be very honest, is there a way that I can check?

Comment: You can check API logs to see the API response. Or you could check in browser e.g. in chrome -> More Tools -> Developer Tools -> Application -> Cookies https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cookies/

Comment: Oh right on the browser after logging in with graphql playground I am not getting any cookies in Application -> Cookies

Comment: if you go to the Network tab in Chrome check the response of the API i.e., whether the API is returning the cookie in response.

Comment: In the Network tab, I am still not receiving any cookies under the Response Headers

Comment: Then your API is not sending it.. Check your backend API code and logs whether it is setting the cookie in the HTTP response.

Comment: i just tried to   

let response = redisClient.ping();

  console.log(response);

and it logged false, I guess my server got disconnected with my redis, but it was working earlier and I didnt change the code

Comment: however, when i close the redis-server itself my backend would log that it is not connected. So I dont even know if I am connected to the redis-server or not when it is running

Comment: i suggest break it down into smaller tasks... mock redis and test whether cookie is set in browser.. and once that is working then implement the redis part...

Comment: I will try that out, thanks Vikram